# Unable to send data using QSerialPort

Tags: qt, c++11, serial-port, uart

I am trying to write a QT application that will be able to communicate with my embedded system using serial port. For now I am testing the config with [Null Modem emulator](https://sourceforge.net/projects/com0com/) as I don't have the embedded system ready yet.

The emulator works fine as I have tested it in other software like Terraterm, RealTerm or Putty. My problem is that my example code doesn't work - it doesn't send the string to another com port.

This is my code:

```
void CSettingsDialog::on_pbSerialCheck_clicked()
{
    QSerialPort serial;
    serial.setPortName(ui->cbSerialPort->currentText());

    if (!serial.open(QIODevice::ReadWrite))
    {
        QMessageBox::warning(this, tr("Serial port"),
                             tr("Serial port %1 is busy!")
                            .arg(ui->cbSerialPort->currentText()));
    }
    else
    {
        serial.setBaudRate(QSerialPort::Baud115200);
        serial.setDataBits(QSerialPort::Data8);
        serial.setParity(QSerialPort::NoParity);
        serial.setStopBits(QSerialPort::OneStop);
        serial.setFlowControl(QSerialPort::NoFlowControl);
        serial.write("TEST\n");
        serial.close();
    }
}
```

I am certain that I have everything set correctly looking at the QT examples.

Comment: check the return value of write()

Comment: Can you try removing the close();

Comment: I had close commented out in the beggining, it didnt help. I dont have the pc now so I cant check the write right now.

Comment: as the object is created on the heap, it would be destroyed when leaving the block anyway and should implicitly call close() in its dtor. So the close should be fine. Try with waitForBytesWritten() between write and close, I'm not sure if QSerialPort does any buffering and asynchronous writing.

Comment: @FrankOsterfeld Stack, not heap.

Comment: Right, freudian slip or something ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am certain that I have everything set correctly looking at the QT
>   examples. I would aprichiate all help!

When reading [flush](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qserialport.html#flush) documentation, it seems that calling "write" buffers, with writes possible finishing asynchronously.

Also see ["Certain subclasses of...are asynchronous"](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qiodevice.html#details), with comments on [waitForBytesWritten](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qiodevice.html#waitForBytesWritten)

Comment: This was the problem, waiting for bytes written solved the case.